# Is it better to initiate a new variable every time or call one from another class in java?

Tags: java, android

I am programming a game for android in framework called `libgdx`(if that is of any importance).

So I have about 8 different classes and in each one I need to measure things relatively to screen size so I make variables *width* and *height*.

My question is:

***Is it better (for performance) to initiate new width and height variables in every class or just make them in one class and call them from other classes every time I need them??***

Comment: call them from other classes whenevr required..!!btw show some codes

Comment: Are you talking about a `width` and `height` for the constant size of the screen (that won't change once the app is launched, but will be different from device to device)?  Either way, from a performance standpoint, I wouldn't worry about a couple primitive variables being duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more efficient to use a single pair of height and width variables and access them elsewhere, as you're using less memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an abstract class and declare these variables accordingly. Then using a getter you could retrieve these values in the other class.

By employing an abstract class you would be able to maintain some sort of a default hight and width and override it whenever required.